# Fixed Div disappears in mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile, css-position

On a site that I'm working on, there is a menu that is a fixed div that shows when the screen width is less than 769px.

A fixed div is toggled when the top bar is clicked (and the menu-open class is added).

```
.header nav  {
        position: fixed;
        left: -330px;
        top: 75px;
        background: #87cc33;
        width: 330px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow:auto;
        /* Transitions */
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

.menu.menu-open {
    left: 0px;
}
```

This works fine in desktop browser, but I get some strange behavior when I use a mobile browser (or with Chrome using device mode).

In mobile, there are 2 issues:

1) The menu disappears when the content of the page is scroll-able.  However, the menu toggling still works - if I try to open the menu in device mode using developer tools on Chrome it will not open, but if I disable device mode, the menu is open.

http://jsfiddle.net/yrc2bfn4/

2) If the page content is short enough so that there is no scrolling, the menu displays in device mode.  However, if the device screen is small enough to cause the menu to scroll, then the menu disappears again.

http://jsfiddle.net/q63cke2u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the nav element outside of the header div and change the css `.header nav` to `.menu` and `.header nav ul` to `.menu ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/seanmurrin/yg0b053s/

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{



/****** Full Size JQuery ************/




/****** Mobile Size JQuery ************/
// Show sidebar
$(".header-image").click(function() {
 $('.menu').toggleClass("menu-open");
 $('.header').toggleClass("menu-open");
});

// Show submenu
$(".nav-lvl-1 li").click(function() {
 $(this).find("ul").toggleClass("sub-menu-open-mobile");
 $(this).find("a").toggleClass("sub-menu-open-mobile");
});


});
```

```css
* {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #333333;
}

/* Container CSS Attributes*/
h1 {
 //color: #333333;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


/* Container CSS Attributes*/
h2 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



/* Highlight background color */
::selection {
  background: #6ab014; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #6ab014; /* Gecko Browsers */
}


/**********************************
Containers
**********************************/

/* Container CSS Attributes*/
.container {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0;
}

.h2-container {
 background-color: #6ab014;
}

/********* Side Menu **********/

.menu {
    Display:none;
}



/**********************************************************************/
/********* Start CSS for less than or equal to 768px screen ***********/
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){

 
 .header-upper, .footer-external{
  display:none;
 }
 
 .header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #6ab014;
  z-index: 100001;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("/images/mobile_expand.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 } 
 
 .header.menu-open {
  background-image: url("/images/mobile_retract.svg");
 }
 
 
 .header .header-image  img{
  content:url("/images/logo_mobile.svg");
  height: 50px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-top: 12px;
 }
 
 /********* Disable link to open sub-menu **********/
 .header .header-image a {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 
 /* Stop header from overlapping container */
 .container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .main {
  position: block;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 80em;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 

 
 
 /********* Side Menu **********/
 .menu  {
  position: fixed;
        display:block;
  left: -330px;
  top: 75px;
  background: #87cc33;
  width: 330px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow:auto;
  /* Transitions */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }

 .menu  ul
 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
 }

 
 /* Make menu above others */
 .menu {
  z-index:100;
 }

 /* Open menu CSS */
 .menu.menu-open {
  left: 0px;
 }
 

  
 /********* Navigation Sub-menus **********/
 .menu .nav-lvl-2.sub-menu-open-mobile{
  /* Max-height may have to change with more sublinks */
  max-height: 1000px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
 }

 .menu .nav-lvl-2 {
  background: #a5e25b;
  max-height: 0px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Transitions */
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
 }

 .menu .nav-lvl-2 a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 }
 

 /********* Disable links to open sub-menu **********/
 .has-sub-menu {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

 .menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 }



 /********* Link CSS **********/
 .menu a{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5e25b;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
 }


 
 /******* Mobile dropdown arrow - down *********/
 a.has-sub-menu:not(.sub-menu-open-mobile):before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 290px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 11px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 7px;
 }

 /******* Mobile dropdown arrow - up *********/
 a.has-sub-menu.sub-menu-open-mobile:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 290px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 7px;
 }



 /******* dropdown link css *********/
 a.has-sub-menu:hover:before,
 a.has-sub-menu:focus:before,
 a.has-sub-menu:active:before {
   border-color: transparent #730800;
 }

 a.has-sub-menu:hover:after,
 a.has-sub-menu:focus:after,
 a.has-sub-menu:active:after {
   border-color: #730800;
 }
 
 
 /* Stop header from overlapping container */
 .container.first {
  margin-top: 75px;
 }

 
  
 
}
/********* End CSS for less than or equal to 480px screen ***********/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<body>



<div class="header">
 <div class="header-inner">
  <h1 class="header-image"><a href="/"><img src="/images/logo.svg" /></a></h1>
 </div>
</div>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="nav-lvl-1">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="has-sub-menu" href="/Platform/">Platform</a>
            <ul class="nav-lvl-2">
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test4</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li><a class="has-sub-menu" href="/modules/">Modules</a>
            <ul class="nav-lvl-2">
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test4</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test5</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test6</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test7</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test8</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test9</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test10</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test11</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test12</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/nav">Hosting</a></li>
        <li><a class="has-sub-menu" href="http://google.com/nav">Resources</a>
            <ul class="nav-lvl-2">
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test4</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test5</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li><a class="has-sub-menu" href="/contact/">Contact Us</a>
            <ul class="nav-lvl-2">
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">test3</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>



<!-- Begin Container -->
<div class="container h2-container"> 
 <div class="main">
  <h2> 
   H2 Title
  </h2>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Begin Container -->
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="main">
  
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Container -->

<!-- Begin Container -->
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="main">
  This is content.  
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
 </div>
</div>



<!-- Begin Container -->
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="main">
  This is content.  This is the last container.
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  This is content
  <br><br><br>
  Final content in the document.
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Container -->
```

Comment: That works, but having the nav outside the header breaks the > 768px layouts. Is there a way to do this while keeping the nav in the header, or do I have to figure out how to make the other layouts work with this HTML?

Comment: Add '.menu { display:none;}' before the media query and add 'display:block' to '.menu' inside the media query.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the last comment.  I've tried a couple of things, but no luck.  Here is a js fiddle with the larger screen CSS - could you clarify? http://jsfiddle.net/Lrktq2yy/

Comment: Actually, I got it.  I changed the larger sized CSS to work with your solution.  Thanks